# CreateDomain method not detected in AppDomain class(.NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to load an assembly to a different AppDomain than that of current one. I was suggested to use AppDomain.CreateDomain method for this. But it seems like the AppDomain class in .NET 4.5 doesn't  have CreateDomain() method anymore.

`AppDomain newAppDomain = new AppDomain.CreateDomain();`

CreateDomain is highlighted in red as intellisense is not suggesting any method.
I wonder if there is an alternative way to do this.

Comment: your code is wrong... is it a typing error?

Comment: I was using 'new', that's the reason for error

Answer (score 1):

`CreateDomain` needs a name for the new app domain:

```
AppDomain newAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNewAppDomain");
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Got it.. i was using 'new'

Comment: ... and not passing a parameter to `CreateDomain`